# Our ASP.Net MVC app runs the 32bit machine.config, how can I make it use the 64bit?

Tags: asp.net, machine.config

It was brought to my attention that our app uses the 32bit machine.config, not the 64bit version (found in 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config').

Is it as easy (grin) as changing the Platform target in the Build properties for the project?

Should I maintain similar settings in both machine.config files?

Where can I learn more?

I did a Bing search, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

Another note, our project is currently set to run in IIS Express when debugging.

Comment: Is your build target set to any cpu? IIS not set to Enable 32 bit applications?

Comment: Yes, build target is Any CPU, and in IIS, the DefaultAppPool (which this uses) is set to Enable 32bit applications.

Comment: Turn off enable 32 bit applications. When it is enabled, it'll use the 32 bit machine config

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't change it.

Comment: Check the IIS Express version in Programs. If you are using IIS 7 Express you are out of luck.